# I have debug it for 4 hours,but I still can't find the BUG

Tags: c, linux, realloc, freopen

This is program is input some string from a file, then, push strings into **LineBuf** one by one, after we push one string into **LineBuf**, print **LineBuf**,then, make **LineBuf** empty.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *LineBuf = NULL;
int BufLen = 0;

void PushToBuf(char c)
{
    LineBuf = (char *)realloc(LineBuf, (BufLen+2)*sizeof(char));
    LineBuf[BufLen] = c;
    BufLen++;
    LineBuf[BufLen] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char temp[20];
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input", "r");

    while (fgets(temp, 20, fp) > 0)
    {
        /*Push temp into buf*/
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
            PushToBuf(temp[i]);

        /*print buf*/
        printf("%s\n", LineBuf);
        printf("%d\n", BufLen);

        /*make buf empty*/
        free(LineBuf);
        BufLen = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my input stream:

```
This is a test. Good evening
bye~
```

This is run result:

```
This is a test file
19
. Good evening

15
 glibc detected  ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000023fa250 

======= Backtrace: =========

/lib/libc.so.6(+0x775b6)[0x7f2ad01bf5b6]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x7f2ad01c5e83]
./a.out[0x400868]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f2ad0166c4d]
./a.out[0x400699]
```

Comment: You should set LineBuf to NULL after calling free()

Comment: 4 hours isn't that much for finding a bug; some bugs will take you 4 weeks!!! For this one, `valgrind` would have helped you.

Comment: @user1103180 please use question headings that are more related to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How [`realloc ( void * ptr, size_t size )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) works:

> The size of the memory block pointed to by the `ptr` parameter is
>   changed to the `size` bytes, expanding or reducing the amount of memory
>   available in the block. The function may move the memory block to a new location, in which
>   case the new location is returned.
>
> In case that `ptr` is `NULL`, the function behaves exactly as `malloc`,
>   assigning a new block of `size` bytes and returning a pointer to the
>   beginning of it.

In your case the pointer is already freed, but still isn't `NULL`, so when the program tries to move this memory block, it causes memory corruption.

To solve it, you should do one of the following:

- Remove `free()`.
- Use `malloc` instead of `realloc`.
- Set `LineBuf` to NULL after `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

This does not make LineBuf empty.  It free the storage space for LineBuf.  When you later realloc LineBuff it attemps to realloc freed space.

```
    /*make buf empty*/
    free(LineBuf);
```

to solve the provlem move the free out of the while loop. and empty free buff byt setting all of the data it stores to null.

for(int i =0; i < BuffLen)
    LineBuf[i]='\0';

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `realloc` a `free`'d pointer; you can't do that!

Answer (score 0):

free(LineBuf) is freeing the memory, but you are using LineBuf again later when calling realloc. You should set LineBuf to NULL after freeing it, then the realloc will do malloc and not reallocate. Keep in mind, it is always good practice to set pointers to NULL after freeing them. This helps detect if you are using pointers to freed memory.

BTW, looking at your code I am not quite sure what you intend to do. Depending on what you want to do you might get rid of LineBuf or of fgets. Also: calling strlen for every i is not very performant, you might better check for temp[i] != '\0'.

Comment: this program only for test~.I write a bigger program, but I found that **PushToBuf** function has some small problems, after a various kinds of trying, I copied the function and write a small program to fix my code.